# Android - Transferir dados e mudar Fragment por Clique

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-activity

Oi, galera. Eu preciso de ajuda para transferir de Fragment quando eu clicar no meu botão dentro de uma ListView.

Atualmente eu tenho uma MainActivity (extends AppCompatActivity) para gerenciar os Fragments.

Abaixo tem algumas imagens de como está o App

Fragment 1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ItemListView:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fragment 2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero que quando eu clique no botão de busca ele vá para o Fragment 2 passando o Id ou o objeto completo para esse outro fragmento.

Tentei pelo Adapter, mas fiquei perdido quando a questão é transferir de um Fragment para outro.

No adapter tenho algo como:

```
 holder.search = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_search);
            holder.search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Código para transferir o Fragment aqui?
                }
            });
```

Como resolver esse problema? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, Victor. Vou escrever um código bem rápido aqui para tentar te auxiliar. Essa transferências de dados entre Fragments vai sempre ter a Activity como intermediária. O Fragment que recebeu o click vai passar o elemento para a Activity e a Activity vai transferir o elemento para o segundo Fragment.

Então, para começarmos, a ideia é que sua Activity implemente uma interface que o Fragment que sofrerá o click conheça e chame. Então, vamos criar a tal interface que será chamada quando houve o click no fragment:

```
public interface OnPesquisarClickListener  {
    public void onPesquisarClick(MeuObjeto meuObjeto);
}
```

E vamos então fazer com que a Activity herde dessa interface e implemente o método:

```
public class MinhaActivity extends AppCompact implements OnPesquisarClickListener {

    //... Outros métodos comuns da Activity

    public void onPesquisarClick(MeuObjeto meuObjeto) {
       //Transfira o objeto para o fragmento dois aqui. Por exemplo, fragmentoDois.pesquisar(meuObjeto)...
    }

}
```

Certo, agora no seu fragment que sofrerá o click, durante o método `onAttach()`, que é chamado durante o ciclo de vida do fragment quando uma o fragment é anexado a Activity, capture a Activity usando polimorfismo para termos em mãos uma instância dê OnPesquisarClickListener. Dessa forma:

```
public void FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

   OnPesquisarClickListener onPesquisarClickListener

   @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        if(context instanceof OnPesquisarClickListener) {
            onPesquisarClickListener = (OnPesquisarClickListener) context;
        }
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    //Métodos comuns ao fragment
}
```

E naquele método que você descreveu vai chamar a instancia de OnPesquisarClickListener que recebemos:

```
holder.search = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_search);
            holder.search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //onPesquisarClickListener.onPesquisarClick(...
                }
            });
```

Qualquer dúvidas é só falar que tento explicar de outras formas. Abs!

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria. Valeu mesmo, cara. Ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 0):

Tássio, Boa noite.

Mano eu estou com uma duvida bem parecida, porém continuei na duvida. Pois o meu é dentro de um Recycle view.

```
//Configuração evento de clique
    recyclerBook.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(
                    getActivity(),
                    recyclerBook,
                    new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                            Book book = new Book();
                            book.setTitle(book.getTitle());
                            book.setWriter(book.getWriter());
                            book.setThumbnailHd(book.getThumbnailHd());

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        }
                    }
            )
    );
```

e como eu pegarias essas informações no outro Fragment?