# Como mudar a Activity dentro de um fragment com Button?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-activity

Eu tenho um App simples, possui duas áreas, uma com a **Fragment** e outra com um **Grupo de Botões** (ImageButtons)

**Como fazer** para que ao clicar nos botões eu consiga alterar qual Activity será carregada no Fragment?

E como manter salvo o estado da ultima Activity aberta?

**Exemplo:** Na Activity 1 ele escreveu o nome dele, se eu for até a 2 e voltar, ainda vai estar lá o nome escrito.

***ps: Não estou usando ListView com TwoWay, é apenas uma ScrollView***

Obs.: Não tem relação com a pergunta  **[Android - Transferir dados e mudar Fragment por Clique](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131916/android-transferir-dados-e-mudar-fragment-por-clique)** Já que uso extends FragmentActivity e ScrollView + ImageButton e preciso da "troca" por OnClickListenner

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Android - Transferir dados e mudar Fragment por Clique](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131916/android-transferir-dados-e-mudar-fragment-por-clique)

Comment: Possível, mas não é, observe que eu disse claramente que não uso ListView, além de usar extends FragmentActivity.

Comment: mas é indiferente, basta vc mudar o listview para o que voce quiser, ou seja, onde tem listview voce pode usar textview, ou listview, ou qualquer outro componente, o fim vai ser o mesmo

Comment: Se fosse simples assim eu já tinha resolvido, mas a Listener de um Botão é totalmente diferente. pq é necessário implementar uma interface... mas de qualquer forma, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, começando pelo inicio.

Quando clicar mudar a atividade:

Eu vou por aqui o codigo que usei num programa:

Codigo do fragmento:
    public class frag_mostrarProduto extends Fragment {

```
    private Button btMostrarProduto_Familia;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public frag_mostrarProduto() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static frag_mostrarProduto newInstance() {
        frag_mostrarProduto fragment = new frag_mostrarProduto();
        //Caso tenhas argumentos gravas aqui:
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        //caso tenhas guardado argumentos, vens buscalos aqui.
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mostrarproduto, container, false);

        btMostrarProduto_Familia = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnoticia);
        btMostrarProduto_Familia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //AQUI faco o i.terminar que e uma funcao feita na atividade onde esta o fragmento!!
              MostrarNoticiaTabbed i = (MostrarNoticiaTabbed)getActivity();
              i.terminar();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Activity: Vou apagar o codigo todo desta atividade e vou so deixar o terminar();

```
public class MostrarNoticiaTabbed extends AppCompatActivity implements frag_mostrarProduto.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ArrayList<Noticia> noticias;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_noticia_tabbed);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mostrar_noticia_tabbed, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return frag_mostrarProduto.newInstance(noticias.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return noticias.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void terminar(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,AtividadePrincipal.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }
```

}

//AQUI ESTA O terminar();

//fazes o finish(); se quiseres "fechar de ves a tividade" se queres que onBackPressed funcione nao uses o finish();

Comment: Obrigado ai pela ajuda Francisco, vou estudar o seu código para entender como fez o tratamento do clique e o savedInstance ^^

Comment: Opa, graças ao seu código, tive uma boa ideia aqui e resolvi meu problema, vlw ai grande. abs :)

Comment: Sempre que precisares :)